# select and show all h2 elements inside their own div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have this Jquery:

```
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        $("h1").after($(all).html());
    }
```

i'm trying to select the `h2` elements on the page, but it seems to only find the first of them and post thrice.

here's the HTML:

```
        <h1>Oversigt</h1>
    <div class="slide">
        <h2>trin 1</h2>
        <p>Tekst til afsnit 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <h2>trin 2</h2>
        <p>Tekst til afsnit 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <h2>trin 3</h2>
        <p>Tekst til afsnit 3.</p>
    </div>
```

And here is a link to the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h766k/)

What i want to do is to post each headline of each div after the `h1` element, so that the page displays:
Oversigt Trin 1 Trin 2 Trin 3

Comment: I could be interpreting this code incorrectly, but did you forget to use `i`?  e.g. `$("h1").after($(all[i]).html());`

Comment: Okay, thanks! This... Kind of works
It is just backwards (starting with the last h2 element)

Comment: That's because it keeps inserting after the `h1`.  So they keep getting wedged in between each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use `i`.  Also because of how you are trying to do this, your elements are going to be reversed.  Here is my suggestion

```
            for (var max = all.length, i = max; i > 0; i--) {
                $("h1").after($(all[i - 1]).html());
            }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3FLxu/

EDIT: this looks cleaner, but either works

```
            for (var max = all.length, i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                $("h1").after($(all[i]).html());
            }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I just couldn't wrap my head around it!

Answer (score 1):

Give the following a try:

```
var $all = $("h2");
$all.each(function() { $("h1").after($(this).html()) });
```

I think you are misunderstanding the way that collections work in jQuery. The reason why the first one is being displayed multiple times is because the loop calls the method multiple times but the `.html()` can only grab the HTML from one of the elements in the collection at a time. As such, instead of throwing an error, it simply grabs that HTML from the first element in the collection.

You can also use the following, as given by @Joseph Marikle in his comment:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    $("h1").after($(all[i]).html());
}
```

This is more similar to the code that you gave, but both do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but this makes the last of the h2 elements show up first (Trin 3Trin 2Trin 1)
Any suggestions on this?

EDIT: Sorry, i get it now.. Joseph Marikle had the answer

Comment: You could use a document fragment and append that rather than append each one individually.

Comment: Good call @JosephMarikle! +1